# Prove that $f(x) = \sqrt{x^2 + x}$ is uniform continuity at the interval $[0, \infty)$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Prove that $f(x) = \sqrt{x^2 + x}$ is uniform continuity at the interval $[0, \infty)$.

There is a hint to the exercise:

Prove that $\forall x,y \geq 1: \frac{x+y+1}{\sqrt{x^2+x}+\sqrt{y^2+y}} \leq 2$

How does the hint help me?

Answer (score 3):

Note that $f$ is continuous on $[0,2]$ so it is uniformly continuous on $[0,2]$.
With the hint, you can show $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[1,\infty)$. 
In fact, we have 
for each $x,y\in [1,\infty)$ that
\begin{align*}
|f(x) -f(y)|&=|\sqrt{x^2 + x}-\sqrt{y^2 + y}|\\
&=\frac{|x^2+x-y^2-y|}{\sqrt{x^2 + x}+\sqrt{y^2 + y}}=|x-y|\frac{x+y+1}{\sqrt{x^2 + x}+\sqrt{y^2 + y}}\le 2|x-y|, 
\end{align*}
which implies that $f$ is actually Lipschitz continuous on $[1,\infty)$.

Could you proceed from here by using the definition of uniform continuity (you may need to select $\delta<1$)?

Comment: How did you get from $|x^2+x-y^2-y|$ to  $|x-y|(x+y+1)$?

Comment: @Alon Because $x^2-y^2+x-y=(x+y)(x-y)+(x-y)=(x+y+1)(x-y)$, then use the fact that $x,y\ge 0$.

Comment: Alon. x^2-y^2 +x-y=(x-y)(x+y)+(x-y)= (x-y)((x+y)+1)

Comment: How can it be that $f$ is continuous at 0, if there is no real root for negative numbers so the left limit at 0, doest exists, no?

Comment: @Alon if you read [the definition of continuity in Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function) carefully, you will see that a function $f:D\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on its domain $D$ does not require $f$ to be defined outside $D$.

Comment: @Alon More precisely, I understand the function $f$ in your question is only defined on $[0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is clearly uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$.

To show uniform continuity on $[1, +\infty\rangle$ notice that for $x \ge 1$ we have

$$f'(x) = \frac{2x+1}{2\sqrt{x(x+1)}} \le \frac{2\cdot 1+1}{2\sqrt{1(1+1)}}= \frac{3}{2\sqrt2}$$

so for $x,y \ge 0$ the mean value theorem gives that there exists $\theta$ between $x$ and $y$ such that

$$|f(x) - f(y)| = |f'(\theta)||x-y| \le \frac{3}{2\sqrt2}|x-y|.$$